# How to specify the number of document to return with elasticSearch and React Native

Tags: react-native, elasticsearch, expo, postman

I'm using react Native and Expo and elasticSearch, I can make my request to my elasticSearch api but i only reseave 10 documents (default size). When i try to add the param "size" they said "unkown parameter". I try it with postman and have the same problem.

[image]

[image]

If someone has any idea to help me

Comment: Can you share your elasticsearch query in JSON format?

Comment: Hi, I don't enderstand, how can i have it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `size` param inside your [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html) or [aggs block](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size).

Comment: https://my-deployment-xxxxx.ent.europe-west3.gcp.cloud.es.io/api/as/v1/engines/bill-search/search?query=Covid&size=15
like that ??

Comment: @xXx_Ninj4_Kill3r_xXx even without size its not returning result, can you share a sample query where its retrurning results?

Comment: @xXx_Ninj4_Kill3r_xXx, I mean your url which you shared thats not returning and result, can you share a link which returns results?

Comment: If I do the same query but without the size param it works fine

Comment: @xXx_Ninj4_Kill3r_xXx https://my-deployment-xxxxx.ent.europe-west3.gcp.cloud.es.io/api/as/v1/engines/bill-search/search?query=Covid returns unknown source to me

Comment: Because i didn't put the id of my serve on stack overflow, but you ca see the screen on my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243170/discussion-between-amit-and-xxx-ninj4-kill3r-xxx).